# navigationController is nil in Swift XCTest case

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xctest

How do you mock/stub navigationController in a test case when you're testing a view controller? I am getting a runtime exception because its nil in my UIViewController when running tests.  You can't set it directly because it's read-only. I'm using Swift 2.2, and XCTest.

Comment: You can initialize a navigation controller and set the view controller under test as its rootViewController.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the comment above, this is possible by instantiating a UINavigationController and adding the view controller you are trying to test to its view array.  Code:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let yourViewController = YourUIViewController()
navigationController.viewControllers = [yourViewController]
```